# How do i invoke wso2 esb unsecured proxy service from java program

Tags: wso2, esb

I trying to invoke the proxy service from java program i'm not able to invoke the service. Please give me some sample program to invoke proxy service from java

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. You can use this [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) in order to make sure your question is not missing anything important.

Comment: 1) I wrote one DSS service to get data from database

Comment: 2)To post data i wrote another dss service

Comment: 3)I have mapped these two services in ESB Proxy service and now i want invoke tis proxy service from java

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434170/accessing-wso2-esb-proxy-in-java-program